# C - passing variable arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm writing  essentially an implementation of `printf`. I want  it so you can pass many strings within strings, e.g.:

```
kprintf("Hello %s", "Goodbye %s", "Farewell\n");
```

Don't ask why, it may very well be insane. Anyway, it recursively calls itself after looking for how many % characters are in the string it is passing; so if more than one % is in it, it should pass many arguments. However, I've been unable to achieve this with any elegance, see the below one:

```
case 1:
    kprintf(str, argus[0]);
break;
case 2:
    kprintf(str, argus[0], argus[1]);
break;
case 3:
    kprintf(str, argus[0], argus[1], argus[2]);
break;
case 4:
    kprintf(str, argus[0], argus[1], argus[2], argus[3]);
break;
case 5:
    kprintf(str, argus[0], argus[1], argus[2], argus[3], argus[4]);
break;
```

With `argus` as an array of pointers. This works, but I hate it. Is there a way to pass variable arguments to a function ?

Comment: What about `kprintf("%d %s", 47, "%u", 11);`, should that work like Python's `"%d %s" % (47, "%u" % 11)` and print `47 11`? If so, good luck! :)

Comment: What if you write a version that takes in a `va_arg` pointer (like `vprintf` does)?

Answer (score 3):

There is a type to do your work. It is called "va_list" and you can feed it with arguments (4096 at most, I guess). In order to use it, include `starg.h`-header and you'll need to use ellipses `...` in your function declaration.

```
int kprintf(int count, ...){
va_list vl;
va_start(vl,count);
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
val=va_arg(vl,double);
printf (" [%.2f]",val);
}
va_end(vl);
}
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/) for an example.

Comment: Bear in mind, that you have to know argument type when you are retrieveing it.

Comment: @Losiowaty yep, absolutely true

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4181/Variable-Argument-Functions) you can find an article about variable argument functions, with downloadable source code, which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be possible to write something that parses `%<something>` inside the strings passed to `%s`, it is generally not how it is done in C/C++.

If you want to put a formatted string into a `printf` statement, you use `sprintf()` to format the first string (in a temporary buffer), then pass that string to the actual `printf` function. Yes, that involves an extra step, but it makes the code much easier - if you are parsing strings passed into `printf`, you pretty much would have to make `printf` recursive [or have some sort of `stack` inside the printf, to track what you are doing].